# Under what conditions does the stringizing preprocessor operator add an _T?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, preprocessor, visual-studio-macros

The following code doesn't compile in my VC++ 2010 project:

```
define MY_MAJOR_VERSION   20
define OLESTR_(str)       L##str
define MOLE( STR )        OLESTR_(#STR)
define MAKE_STR(STR)      MOLE(STR)

REGMAP_ENTRY(MAKE_STR(VERSION), MAKE_STR(MY_MAJOR_VERSION))
```

`VERSION` is NOT a macro definition, just text. In the end, I want:

```
REGMAP_ENTRY(L"VERSION", L"20")
```

but what I get, when I compile in Debug mode is:

```
REGMAP_ENTRY(L"VERSION", LL"20")
```

I'm thinking it's a project setting because I've used that in debug mode in other situations, but never with this problem. Is there a VC++ 2010 setting that would cause the stringizing operator to insert an `L` or `_T`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this (note that I changed `MAKE_STR` to `MAKE_OLESTR` - I assume that was a typo in the code posted in the question):

```
#define MY_MAJOR_VERSION   20
#define OLESTR_(str)       L##str
#define MOLE( STR )        OLESTR_(#STR)
#define MAKE_OLESTR(STR)      MOLE(STR)

REGMAP_ENTRY(MAKE_OLESTR(VERSION), MAKE_OLESTR(MY_MAJOR_VERSION))
```

preprocesses to (as shown by `cl /E test.c`):

```
REGMAP_ENTRY(L"VERSION", L"20")
```

which seems to be what you want.

You may want to post something that can reproduced using a command line compile.